# Rails Joins table: how to collect data by parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have two objects:
`Project` & `Specialty`.

They are connected with a joins table: `ProjectSpecialty`

Models are as follows:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_specialty
  has_many :specialties, :through => :project_specialty
end
```

```
class Specialty < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_specialty
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_specialty
end
```

```
class ProjectSpecialty < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :specialty
end
```

I'm trying to call a collection of Projects that are filtered by `Specialty`.

Controller:

```
def index
    @projects = Project.all
    if params[:project_specialty].present?
      @specialty = Specialty.find(params[:project_specialty])
      @projects = Project.where(specialties: @specialty.id)
    end
  end
```

This only returns one record when I run this index action, even though there are multiple Projects that have a given specialty.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The *rails way* to define a nested resource is:

```
resources :specialities do
  resources :projects, only: [:index]
end
```

This gives you the route `/specialities/:speciality_id/projects`.

You can set your controller up as:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /projects
  # GET /specialities/1/projects
  def index
    if params[:speciality_id].present?
      @specialty = Specialty.find(params[:specialty_id])
      @projects = @specialty.projects
    else
      @projects = Project.all
    end
  end
end
```

But you can also use a seperate controller for the nested context:

```
resources :specialities do
  resources :projects, only: [:index], 
                       module: :specialities 
end
```

```
module Specialities 
  class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    # GET /specialities/1/projects
    def index
      @specialty = Specialty.find(params[:specialty_id])
      @projects  = @specialty.projects
    end
  end
end
```

The advantage is that this controller only does a single job.